# Scrollbars hidden in Lion. How do people scroll horizontally if they aren't using a trackpad?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nsscrollview, osx-lion

I have an app that has a list of tags on the bottom of the window. This list grows over time and needs to be scrolled horizontally. This was fine before, but now in Lion they scrollbars automatically hide. If using a mouse without a horizontal scroll, there's basically no way to scroll these now in Lion. What are the best practices here to solve the issue? Do I need to get rid of the scrollview and change it to a "More" list or something?

Answer (score 14):

If the user doesn't have a device available which supports touch-based scrolling (e.g, a touchpad, Magic Trackpad, or Magic Mouse), the horizontal scrollbar won't be hidden by default. It's controlled by this preference option:

[image: This preference controls it]